# How can we find when the file was updated in Windows folder?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have one file name file.txt that was deployed in 2018 and this file used to be updated daily by Autosys jobs. In order to troubleshoot when it is updated by wrong info or details. I want to find when it was updated last. As file's time stamp is the deployed date and the Autosys job completed stating the file has been updated. But the data file contain is old.

Thank You

Comment: Does "Date Modified" appear on your folder containing the txt file?

Comment: yes, i have date modified column in folder, it shows deployed date of the file. Whereas the data the file contain used to update everyday. Data is huge i want to know whether the data s updated today or it is from yesterday only.